# shifting the bits. What's happening in this code?

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I've tried really hard, but I can't seem to understand what's going on in this code. Can anyone please shed some light?

```
public class BitArrary
{
    private Byte[] m_byteArray;
    private Int32 m_numBits;


    public BitArrary(Int32 numBits)
    {
        if (numBits <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Must be greater then 0");

        m_numBits = numBits;
        m_byteArray = new Byte[(numBits + 7) / 8];
    }

    public Boolean this[Int32 bitPos]
    {
        get
        {
            if ((bitPos < 0) || (bitPos >= m_numBits))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bitPos");
            }
            else
            {
                return (m_byteArray[bitPos / 8] & (1 << (bitPos % 8))) != 0;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if ((bitPos < 0) || (bitPos > m_numBits))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bitPos");
            if (value)
            {
                m_byteArray[bitPos / 8] = (Byte)(m_byteArray[bitPos / 8] | (1 << (bitPos % 8)));
            }
            else
            {
                m_byteArray[bitPos / 8] = (Byte)(m_byteArray[bitPos / 8] & ~(1 << (bitPos % 8)));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I don't get the parts (the three lines) where there is operation on bits. As far as I get it, in first one, its `ANDing` the value of bit array to find if that bit is on. In second one, its `ORing`, and in the third one `ANDing` with `NOT`, is that about right what I think is happening in these three lines?

Whats really hurting my brain in what is this doing `1 << (bitPos % 8)`? And what does `ANDing`, `ORing` or `ANDing` with `NOT` of it, is going to do? What I know is that you can left or right shit a value of something (or other, I am not really clear on this.) So what is this doing? is it shift `1` or what?

Can anyone please explain?

**EDIT : Edited for full code...**

Comment: Looks like an indexed property to return the bits of a byte, returns true/false for each bits postion (set/unset respectively), I will post an answer with the detail :)

Comment: See this post:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883384/practical-applications-of-bitwise-operations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok looks like the is a private field which contains the bytes (m_byteArray) and this gets a bit from the bytearray (I'm assuming that the bytearray is contiguous and this attempts to get the bits from a certain position - e.g. imagine there are 3 bytes, position 13 would get bit 5 from byte 2)

Edit: To summarise better

Image we have 3 bytes in the byte array

```
00101011 00101010 01000010
```

If we want bit 13 we would pass '12' to the indexer **IMPORTANT TO REMEMBER!!**

```
00101011 00101010 01000010
-------------^
(Remember it's 0 based)
```

We go

```
m_byteArray[12 / 8] (12 / 8 = 1 so we know we want byte number two at index 1 - byte array is also zero based!)
```

So we have the second byte (at index 1)

```
00101010
----^
```

Now we go

```
00101010 & (1 << (12 % 8))
```

Which is equivalent to

```
00101010 & 00000001 << 4
```

Which is

```
00101010 & 00001000
```

So this masks off to

```
1 & 1
```

Which returns 1 :)

For masks that end up as

```
1 & 0
```

Logically that returns 0

Comment: I've updated the question to include the full code..
Though really thanks for such a nice explanation.. :)

Comment: Sorry I think it was a bit confusing first time round, I've clarified it by putting a step by step of the bytes

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
return (m_byteArray[bitPos / 8] & (1 << (bitPos % 8))) != 0;
```

returns whether the nth bit in a byte array is set.

`bitPos / 8`

finds the byte in which the indexed bit is in, and

```
1 << (bitPos % 8))
```

creates a bitmask for the associated byte.

As an example, if you wanted to find whether the 10th bit was set, `bitPos` would be 9.
`bitPos / 8` = 1, so the associated bit is in the second byte within the array.
`bitPos % 8` = 1, so the expression (1 << (bitPos % 8)) creates a bitmask of `00000010`. Applying this mask to `byteArray[1]` will return 1 if the second bit is set, or 0 otherwise.

The logic for the setters is similar, except that

```
m_byteArray[bitPos / 8] | (1 << (bitPos % 8))
```

will set the bit in the associated position, while

```
(m_byteArray[bitPos / 8] & ~(1 << (bitPos % 8))
```

will clear it.